# Formatar mascara para atributo TimeStamp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotation

Preciso apresentar o valor do atributo HORAINICIO apenas HH:mm (hora e minutos). Ao incluir as mascaras abaixo ocorre um erro:

**A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto.**

Tentei das duas formas:

```
@dia.HORAINICIO.ToString(@"hh:mm tt")
@dia.HORAINICIO.ToString("{0:t}")
```

O meu data Annotation está da seguinte forma:

```
[Display(Name = "Hora Inicial:")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
public TimeSpan HORAINICIO { get; set; }
```

Comment: Tenta assim: @dia.HORAINICIO.ToString("hh:mm"); ou @dia.HORAINICIO.ToString("hh:mm:ss"); com segundos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta sem o 'tt' na máscara.

```
string test ="08:00:00";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(test);
Console.Write(ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```

Fiz um [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=CozbzNSCGc) para você, acho que irá te atender.

Comment: valeu user3517631 deu certo..